# MySQL Timestamps transferred using AWS-DMS seem to be a mixture of GMT and BST

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I'm using AWS-DMS to copy a local MySQL database into an AWS-RDS MySQL database.
I am finding the fields that are TIMESTAMP will differ from source to destination, but only for date/times that are in BST (British Summer Time - Daylight Saving Time).
The source is GMT and the destination is UTC (Checked using `select @@system_time_zone , @@time_zone ;`)

So, for example, 2021-11-30 09:47:00 is correctly migrated to 2021-11-30 09:47:00 but
2021-07-08 **12**:27:15 is migrated to 2021-07-08 **11**:27:15

I have found details of the DMS setting ServerTimezone that will define what the time zone is for the endpoint. I have added "ServerTimezone": "GMT" to the source endpoint. I understand that GMT and UTC are the same, but I tried it (no difference).

My question is, how do I get the timestamp to be copied exactly as stored in the source?
Is there a ServerTimezone value I can use in the DMS endpoint?

I can understand that the timestamp stored in the source is actually in GMT + 1 hour (in the summer) and it's migrated as GMT. That would explain the hour difference for the BST timestamps only, BUT doesn't a timestamp get saved in the current timezone, which in this case should be GMT?

Comment: It may or may not be related but, are you aware that `TIMESTAMP` columns are stored internally as UTC and converted to local time zone on display?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález is that strictly true? I thought timestamps were stored in the @@system_time_zone.
In any case, if the timestamp of 12:00 UTC is stored and then displayed using GMT (the time zone of the database) it should still be 12:00, but I'm seeing it migrated as 11:00 when BST (DST) is in operation.

Comment: [It is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html): "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval." — It's counter-intuitive so it's easy to do a wrong diagnostic either in source or in destination. You can [convert to Unix time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to double-check. (I don't know anything about DMS).